# Nginx 'if' doesn't work properly

Tags: if-statement, nginx, args

I have some problem with nginx. Here is my simple virtualhost config that doesn't seem to work properly:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name my.site;

    access_log /home/my.site/www/my.site/log/access.log;
    error_log /home/my.site/www/my.site/log/error.log error;
    root   /home/my.site/www/my.site/public/;

    charset utf-8;

    location /search/ {
        error_page 418 = @passenger;
        recursive_error_pages on;

        if ( $arg_mode = block ) { return 418; }
        default_type text/html;
        try_files $request_uri @passenger;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @passenger;
    }

    location @passenger {
        root   /home/my.site/www/my.site/public/;
        passenger_enabled on;
    }

}
```

The problem exactly is with the location /search/. I want nginx to pass the request immediately to the backend if uri includes the parameter 'mode' with the value 'block' (i.e. uri looks like `http://my.site/search/word?mode=block&type=... (other parameters)` )

But now it doesn't work. If static file /public/search/word exists server sends it even if parameter mode=block exists in uri... What is my misstep?

Comment: Are you sure it's not passenger sends file?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is fine Nginx wise and any request for /search/ with mode=block will get sent to @passenger.

A simple test case is ...

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server example.com;  
    location /search/ {
        error_page 418 = @passenger;
        recursive_error_pages on;
        if ( $arg_mode = block ) { return 418; }
        default_type text/html;
        echo "/search/";
    }
    location @passenger {
        echo "@passenger!";
    }
}
```

Calling this using curl ...

```
# curl -i http://example.com/search/word/?mode=block&a=b$c=d

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 02 Oct 2014 11:35:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive

@passenger!
```

So, if files are getting served, then this is happening in the @passenger block as @Alexey Ten inferred in his comment.